TanStack Table - sticky column not working - Radix UI
I’m having issues getting the first column of my table to be sticky. I think I’m missing some CSS that sets the container of the scroll area to 100vw, but even after setting it, I still don't get my sticky column.
If the table is a fixed width, then I have the sticky column with no problem, but when I make the columns able to be resized, I encounter this issue.
I made an live example https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/qpcdv2

